# Side-by-side meaning

Tags: meaning, word-order

`A near future, where humans have been defeated by the viral parasites named Gastrea. They have been exiled into a small territory and live in despair, side-by-side in terror.`, when they said `side-by-side`, what did they mean? and when they started a new paragraph after the `.`, they started with `They`, who are `They`? The humans or the `Gastrea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the humans have been defeated then it is they who have been exiled not the Gastrea. The humans are confined close together in the small territory.

> "side-by-side"
>
> 1. (of two or more people or things) close together and facing the same way. "on we jogged, side by side, for a mile" synonyms: alongside
>      (each other), beside each other, abreast, level, shoulder to shoulder,
>      cheek by jowl, together, **close together** 
>      https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=side-by-side+definition

Comment: I thought they meant `Gastrea` that's why I didn't get it, thanks!